# How To Add new API Controller VisualStudio For Mac

Tags: .net, macos, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-core-3.1

I am getting started with ASP.Net Core 3.1 Api Projects on Visual Studio For Mac.
I have created the default template generated "Weather Forecast" Controller spitting out default weather ForeCast data.

Now I want to add a controller to do what i need it to do. "tripcalc"

So I added a Controller scaffolding for "tripcalc" Then went and changed launchsettings.json to point to my new "tripcalc" controller. **It still showed the WeatherController Data** I wonder Why? I suppose i need to change Startup.cs too in some way. FYI I did a file Search for all occurences in all file endings for "WeatherForecast" it existed nowhere

```
{
  {
    "$schema": "http://json.schemastore.org/launchsettings.json",
    "iisSettings": {
      "windowsAuthentication": false,
      "anonymousAuthentication": true,
      "iisExpress": {
        "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:22536",
        "sslPort": 44363
      }
    },
    "profiles": {
      "IIS Express": {
        "commandName": "IISExpress",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "launchUrl": "tripcalc",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        }
      },
      "TripCalculator.API": {
        "commandName": "Project",
        "launchBrowser": true,
        "launchUrl": "tripcalc",
        "environmentVariables": {
          "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
        },
        "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5003;http://localhost:5002"
      }
    }
  }
```

Startup.cs

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace TripCalculator.API
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh an update... I typed the url to /tripcalc and it showed me the correct data....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was just in the startup parameters

[image]